Is a question about how much the Japapenese Duolingo course can teach you on topic?
I want to ask a question about how much the Japanese Duolingo course can teach you (on average). I also want to know the maximum amount of knowledge the course can teach you, and what your knowledge of the skill will be compared to an average native speaker (I'd like to know this for how much the course teaches on average too).
Is this on topic?

Your question is (I think) on-topic here on meta. It would not be on-topic on the main site.
My personal opinion:

Duolingo is useful for building up a base vocabulary.
It is completely inadequate for teaching grammar.
It is diabolical at teaching natural, or even correct, pronunciation; the AI generated voices butcher the language and frequently produce the wrong readings for the kanji.

This is based on my experience of going through the whole course two or three years ago. Things may have improved since, but the trend appeared to be in the opposite direction.
